# serier to tolist() gives elements in squared brackets when appended python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tolist

When i convert the series object to list and append each element to a new list the elements are added with extra squared brackets.

Can someone help me on how to remove the brackets or append without adding extra bracket for each element

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[10,20,30],'col2':[40,50,60]})
print(df.head())
df_fd = pd.DataFrame({'variable':['col1','col1','col1','col2','col2','col2'],'Value':[10,20,30,40,50,60],'ratio':[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6]})

print(df_fd)

df_new = pd.DataFrame()
print(df.head())
for col in df.columns:
    ratio_list = []
    print('Columns:',col)
    for val in df[col].unique():
        print('Instance:',val)
        print('Ratio value:',(df_fd.loc[(df_fd['variable'] == col) & (df_fd['Value'] == val)]['ratio']))
        ratio = df_fd.loc[(df_fd['variable'] == col) & (df_fd['Value'] == val)]['ratio']
        ratio = list(ratio)
        print('ratio:',ratio)
        ratio_list.append(ratio)
        print(ratio_list)
    df_new['ratio'] = ratio_list    
    df_new.rename(columns={"ratio":"Ratio_"+col},inplace=True)
    print(df_new.head())

df = pd.concat([df,df_new],axis=1)
print(df.head())
```

```
I get output something like this :
[[0.1], [0.2], [0.3]] 

col1  col2 Ratio_col1 Ratio_col2
0    10    40      [0.1]      [0.4]
1    20    50      [0.2]      [0.5]
2    30    60      [0.3]      [0.6]
```

Comment: If you do not want a list of list, do not append lists to lists; add just the number instead. You are casting `ratio` into list at `ratio = list(ratio)`

Comment: ratio is a series object which looks something like this :
ratio ---- 0    0.1
Name: ratio, dtype: float64

and i want the value 0.1 to be part of the list

Comment: Why would you not then just take the first (and only?) value of that series? `ratio_list.append(ratio[0])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ratio = df_fd.loc[(df_fd['variable'] == col) & (df_fd['Value'] == val)]['ratio'].values[0]
```

remove

- ratio=list(ratio)

Comment: Thanks you so much!!! Works

Comment: u r welcome : )